# Spring Boot Auditing - map current user to @CreatedBy, @LastModifiedBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So I have an audit class that is using @MappedSuperClass, it updates the values createdBy and updatedBy but it does not add a foreign key on the User entity, so there's no database validation

Here's the Audit Class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdBy", "updatedBy"},
        allowGetters = true
)
public abstract class UserDateAudit extends DateAudit {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    public Long createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "updated_by", nullable = false)
    public Long updatedBy;
}
```

I searched on how to do this using @Inheritance but did not completely get it.
so How do I achieve the connection between this class and User entity?

**Edit 1**
Here's the auditing configuration I implement.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AuditingConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Long> auditorProvider() {
        return new SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl();
    }

}

class SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Long> {

    @Override
    public Optional<Long> getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null ||
                !authentication.isAuthenticated() ||
                authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Optional.ofNullable(userPrincipal.getId());
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
to set clear what exactly I mean
so how to use something other than @MappedSuperclass to be able achieve this "I want to be able to map the user reference in all tables that inherit the UserDateAudit so that it is a foreign key for all these table (which would add a validation that the user id actually exist) not just a regular column".

Comment: You need to implement the org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware interface and add the logic to retrieve currently logged in user in the getCurrentAuditor method.
See https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/src/main/java/gt/app/config/AuditorResolver.java for an example

Comment: @OmarAbdelhady the [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-mapped-superclass) inheritance model is not mirrored at the database level, hance fields of `UserDateAudit` class can belong to the different table depends on target entity that extends it. So, your question unclear.

Comment: I know that @MappedSuperclass is not mirrored, so how to use something else to be able achieve this "what to use to be able to map the user reference in all tables that inherit the UserDateAudit so that it is a foreign key for all these table (which would add a validation that the user id actually exist) not just a regular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware` interface and add the logic to retrieve currently logged in user in the `getCurrentAuditor` method.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditorResolver implements AuditorAware<YOUR_TYPE> {
 
    @Override
    public Optional<YOUR_TYPE> getCurrentAuditor() {

        //code to retrieve the currently logged in user and return the id/user object 
    }
}
```

See this for an example: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/src/main/java/gt/app/config/AuditorResolver.java

The documentation also describes it beautifully: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.basics

Comment: Yes that's what I do I will include it in the question.
, but my question is, while doing this how to map the createdBy and updatedBy values to the User table to make hibernate add foreign key that references the user table on every subtype (entity) of that SuperClass

Comment: Did you look at the example code? https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/src/main/java/gt/app/config/AuditorResolver.java

Comment: I did, it's what I am looking for, thanks

Comment: Worked for after I also added to my entities `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`